# Why isn't this popup overlay working correctly?

Tags: html, css, popup, overlay

I am using website builder cargo to make a site and having a problem with a popup overlay. I have replicated the problem but you need to login to see it.

Please login here: https://auth.cargo.site/login

With the following details:

- user: temp4321@malinator.com
- password: temp4321

Then open the live site in another tab: https://temp4321.cargo.site

The intention is for a video popup appear when you click on the image as it is doing but I also want to be able to play the video and be able to click outside the popup to close it. Currently, I can only have the video iframe working or the close function working.

- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fha.jpg) are the steps to see and edit the HTML and CSS using the login above.
- I tried changing the `z-index` but it didn't solve the issue.

**my code:**

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(232, 12, 12, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 50ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.popup {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pop-content {
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(232, 232, 12, 0.7);
}

a.divLink {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
  z-index: 1;
  /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
  background-color: white;
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  opacity: 0;
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
}
```

```html
<a href="#popup1" class="image-link">{image 2}</a>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay full-pointer-events-none">

  <div class="popup">

    <a class="divLink" href="javascript:history.back()"></a>
    <div class="pop-content">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/298200022" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;"></iframe>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expect to be able to both interact with the embedded video and close the popup but currently it's one or the other.

Comment: are you seriously sharing access to your site?

Comment: i just made a disposable one to replicate the problem